# Grouping of data in crystal report

Tags: visual-studio, ms-access-2010, crystal-reports-2008

I am creating a crystal report for employees logs although I succeeded in designing the report as the way i wanted, my only problem is its only showing one user details but printing the logs of the other employees. what i want is to display employee logs data per page. Any help and suggestions will be greatly welcomed. See the query and crystal report design and the result:

```
SELECT LOGDATES.ID, LOGDATES.CHECKDATE, USERINFO.EMPID, USERINFO.USERNAME, USERINFO.DEPTNAME, 
LOGDATES.AMIN, LOGDATES.LUNCHOUT, LOGDATES.LUNCHIN, LOGDATES.PMOUT
FROM USERINFO, LOGDATES
WHERE LOGDATES.ID = USERINFO.USERID
ORDER BY USERINFO.EMPID ASC;
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found the answer by using the grouping section after tweaking crystal reports functions and by googling it. now i am getting the result that i want.
I Grouped the UserID, UserName and their respective departments.

[image]